# Trying to open an excel sheet in C# but getting provider is not installed

Tags: c#, excel

I have installed the 64 bit version of ACE but its not working for some reason.  I keep getting the provider is not not registered on the machine.  I am using the following connection string.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'");
```

Do I need something extra to use 64 bit version?

Comment: Do you have “Prefer 32-bit” checked in project properties, on the “Build” tab?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Soonts, Top Man.  I didn't know that option existed, I unchecked the value and ran the code, it managed to open or fail the file without throwing an error.  Fail meaning it was password protected.  Shame it was a comment rather than an answer otherwise it would have got the "points"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default project settings, .NET apps compiled as “Any CPU” binaries will execute as 32-bit processes even on 64-bit Windows. Not sure why, probably some old compatibility reasons.

Very easy to change. Open project properties, “Build” tab, and uncheck “Prefer 32-bit” checkbox. With that checkbox unchecked, your app will execute as 64 bit process on 64 bit OSes, then you’ll get the 64-bit version of ACE you’ve installed.